# Call a controller method from a View in a proper way

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

As it's mentioned in the title. I What is the best way to call a controller method from a View. ViewBag, HTMLHelper ...?

Answer (score 0):

When user requests a page, web page first find appropriate controller using Routes. Then it completes all serverside C# code. It then fills up html template and send html to user. You can't call controller from view on server. But when view page runs on client browser, you can make ajax call to server and then send data back to controller

here is the example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41828/JQuery-AJAX-with-ASP-NET-MVC

Let me narrow down the steps taken by browser.

1. User requests page

   /Home/Index
2. ASP MVC server sends the request to routes. Default route are in global.aspx file.
3. Route call appropriate controller/action.
4. Action runs server code and optionally sends data to Views.
5. Views templates are filled in and HTML/css/javascript is sent to client.
6. After page load on browser or after clicks by user you can send ajax request back to server

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make it an ActionResult. Also, if you're using an Ajax POST, then the action needs to be marked with the HttpPost attribute. Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult test()
{
    return Content("It works");
}
```

you view.cshtml add javascript tag.

```
// Sample Ajax Request.   
$.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("test", "Home")',
          data: {dealerID: dealerID},
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
         }

});
```

Note:

- Url.Action has the controller/action parameters. should be "ActionName" first, then "ControllerName".
- For Url.Action, if the controller class is "HomeController", then you need just "Home"
- The JQuery options when Request success show alert. -- should be success: function(data) {}.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", "ControllerName")
```